# Multiple resources under one request: RESTful API design pattern

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, wildfly-8

I'm trying to create a GET request, where I have two different requests. Since both resources are related with each other, I'm trying to put them under one 'sub-resource'.
The first one is:

```
  @QueryParam("{customerId}")
  public List<customerModel> getCustomer(@QueryParam("customerId") Long customerId) {....}
```

this fetches the customer's name depending on the customerId

```
@QueryParam("{customerId}/details")
public List<customerDetailModel> getCustomerDetail(@QueryParam("customerId") Long customerId) {....}
```

this fetches the detailed information of the customer (phone number, address, etc.)

I'm running the first one with the following (works fine) :
......?customerId=7453112

but I can't reach the second request when I'm hitting the following URL:
......?customerId=7453112/details

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource methods must be annotated with [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) and with a request method designator such as [`@GET`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/GET.html), [`@POST`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/POST.html), [`@PUT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PUT.html),
[`@DELETE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/DELETE.html), [`@HEAD`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/HEAD.html) or [`@OPTIONS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/OPTIONS.html). Your [`@QueryParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) annotation is misplaced.

By the way, for this situation, you should consider using a *path* parameter instead of a *query* parameter. Hence you should use [`@PathParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html) instead of [`@QueryParam`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html) in the method parameter. For more details on when to use query or path parameters, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36421654/1426227)

Also, not sure why you are returning a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) if you are requesting a resource by its unique identifier. In this situation, you are supposed to return a representation of a single resource (and not a represention of multiple resources).

So your resource class would be as following:

```java
@Path("customers")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public class CustomerResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{customerId}")
    public CustomerModel getCustomer(@PathParam("customerId") Long id) {
        ...
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{customerId}/details")
    public CustomerDetailModel getCustomerDetail(@PathParam("customerId") Long id) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The first endpoint can be requested as following:

```
GET http://example.com/api/customers/1
```

And the second endpoint can be requested as following:

```
GET http://example.com/api/customers/1/details
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go with `@RequestMapping`.

Something like:
`@RequestMapping("/{customerId}")` and `@RequestMapping("/{customerId}/details")`.

Your URL becomes `7453112/details` instead of query params.

Comment: `@RequestMapping` is a Spring annotation. The OP is using JAX-RS.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked the tag and its been long since I worked with Spring, hence that they are new annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `/details` in an `@Path` annotation, and then use the same query parameter, like this:

```
@Path("/details/{customerId}")
public List<customerDetailModel> getCustomerDetail(@PathParam("customerId") Long customerId) {....}
```

Then your URL would look like this:

`.../details/7453112`

Or if you want to keep using it as a query parameter you can do something like this:

```
@Path("/details")
public List<customerDetailModel> getCustomerDetail(@QueryParam("customerId") Long customerId) {....}
```

using this url:

`.../details?customerId=xxx`

Comment: In this particular case, what should be the 'best practice'? I mean should it be just PathParam or should it be QueryParam?

Comment: I think because the customer ID is the subject of the method's functionality, it makes sense to use it as a query param. There is a good question about that here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552248/when-to-use-queryparam-vs-pathparam